# Bean overriding in Spring context that uses both annotation and xml config

Tags: spring, spring-bean

There is a spring project A which is completely annotation based.
I need to override some beans conditionally in project B which is a legacy application using Spring 4.1.3 and uses xml based config.

There is FooConfig which is configuring beans using @ComponentScan. This config is a third party code for me. i.e I do not have access for this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foo.bean"})
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {
}
```

I have created a BarConfig at my end, which imports this FooConfig and overrides some beans based on a condition. This is achieved using @Conditional

```
@Configuration
@Import(FooConfig.class)
public class BarConfig {

    @Bean(name="helloService")
    @Conditional(IsSpanishCondition.class)
    public HelloService getHelloService() {
        return new HelloService() {
            @Override
            public String getGreeting(String name) {
                return "Hola "+name;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And I have included BarConfig in my application-context.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="com.foo.config.BarConfig"/>
```

While this approach works flawlessly in Spring 5.1.2.RELEASE, it does not work in Spring 4.1.3.RELEASE

> 00:14:20.617 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=getHelloService,declaringClass=com.foo.config.BarConfig]: a definition for bean 'helloService' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.

Also, I have observed the same issue in Spring 4 in a completely annotation based context as well. i.e. it is not because of xml and annotation config mix but due to the Spring versions used here

**Questions** 
What changed in Spring 5? 
Is there any rule of thumb while working with a Spring application that uses both xml and annotation config especially when it comes to overriding the beans?

**Also FTR, these are the solutions that worked** 
1.Overriding the beans using BeanPostProcessor
2.Using profiles. But this wouldn't work for complicated conditions.

```
@Profile("ENGLISH")
@Configuration
@Import(FooConfig.class)
public class EnglishConfig {
}
```

```
@Profile("SPANISH")
@Configuration
public class SpanishConfig {
    @Bean(name="helloService")
    public HelloService getHelloService() {
        return new HelloService() {
            @Override
            public String getGreeting(String name) {
                return "Hola "+name;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to override a xml bean from a @Configuration class, now I'm not 100% sure, but in spring 4 a xml bean still had precedence in choosing a bean, so the @Configuration beans would not get permission to overwrite the xml bean. Which was resolved in spring 5.

Your approach to use BeanPostProcessor is i guess the only viable solution for this.

I'm thinking maybe you could use a different bean name, implement your own behaviour and use @Qualifier annotation to choose which bean will get selected?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even when I am not using xml, I get the same error.